# optimizing update statement

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, myisam, bigtable

I am using MyISAM only database and an update on a big tables is taking too much time. The size of the table is around 30 GB (15 GB each for MYD and MYI). Is there anyway I can improve the speed other than looking at the indexes?

Comment: Without seeing your table structure and your update query it is very difficult to help. Please give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyIsam key cache tuning:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/mysql-refman-5.4/optimization.html#myisam-key-cache

General performance optimizations: (there are many)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/mysql-refman-5.5/optimization.html

30 GB is quite large, are you running a high-end server?

Comment: Mysql consumes more than 100% CPU and sometimes CPU is shown 30 - 50% high in top output. Is this normal? Another question is if I select before updating the record, will the cache be used?

Comment: Depends on what machine it is running. I have run small servers before where this is too high, and I've been on shared web-hosts where 100% cpu time is nothing - because it's running 24 cores. However, 30GB is quite high even for a server with many cores and a lot of RAM (many high end servers only handle 32-64 in 2012). If you have a small subset of queries getting frequently accessed, then it may be OK. If you're querying a large set and not much of your db is stored in RAM, your big bottle neck is needing to page those files off the disc into RAM.

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading lots of data in, have a look at bulk insert commands, or even load data infile depending on your specific situation.

If you're doing lots of inserts it's probably worth testing the disabling of keys prior to the inserts.  It may help speed things up.

Using

```
insert into myTable values("rec1","hello"),("rec2","world"),("rec3","cheesy huh");
```

Will insert 3 records in 1 statement - again, you need to test it.

I've done this form of insert with thousands of rows and it works well in my example.

Answer (score 0):

some more notes that may be interessting:

- Change Storage Engine (innodb is better for highvolume tables)
- Partitionate your TABLES (Or whole DB) into more logical slices (e.g. data by year, month, regional etc.) so tables will be more but smaller ones
- Make sure that mysql join buffer sizes and similar metrics are big enough for fast delivering